# MPMoviePlayerViewController - How to keep image on MPMoviePlayerViewController when change Fullscreen?

Tags: iphone, label, mpmovieplayer

```
NSURL *url = [self localMovieURL];
MPMoviePlayerViewController *playerView = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [playerView moviePlayer];

moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:moviePlayer];

[self setMessageLabel];
[playerView.view addSubview:message];

[self.navigationController presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playerView];
```

hello,

somthing wrong .. mpMoviePlayerViewController.

source > 'message (UILabel)' is global variable.

video play > full screen button click > gone label ...

I don't know Why gone label.

anybody help me please .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a hunch but you should try following the `MPMoviePlayerDidEnterFullscreenNotification` notification and then do the following in the notification handler,

```
[message.superview bringSubviewToFront:message];
```

Comment: ! sooo surprise - thank you !! Is very well run. but ... i don't wanna delay for bringSubview. Is there any way I can do?

Comment: There is `MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification` that you can look into.

Comment: /That way, it does not. Once again, thank you. I'm solved ... moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
> moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen; 
this way Did not disappear Label :)